# Jquery ui dragable help (with scroll)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am doing a mobile app and in it i have a horizontal scroll list with dragable items. Under the list i have a box in which is droppable. The dragging seems to work except when i drop into the box nothing happends.

[My code jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PRQyr/1/)

I have a feeling it's because of the overflow and scrolling, but i can't seem to find a fix

Comment: it works - it's just that you didn't specify any action in the drop method :)

Comment: I want the image to appear in the box, but also stay in the list :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the solution in this fiddle update, didn't get what you want to accomplish at first.

http://jsfiddle.net/PRQyr/2/

Basically you need to clone the dragged element and either append it to the droppable container with `append` method or replace content of droppable container with the dragged element with the `html` method.

I believe you'll be able to take it from here :)

Comment: Is there any way to manipulate the objects that are in the #droppable? My goal is to continue to make them draggable and be able to resize the images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're expecting, but when I console.log in the drop it gives me both elements.

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    accept: "img",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
         console.log(event, ui);
    }
});
```

Running this gives me both objects. What is not working?

Comment: Okk, i see. I guess i was expecting something else. I thought it was like drag and drop and i would see the image in the box. Is it possible they way i have it? Or should i check out the html5 drag and drop?

Comment: Look at how they are doing it with the Shopping Cart example. http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#shopping-cart They are doing what you want, but you can checkout their code to see how their keeping the element in the container.

Comment: Alright cool, thanks for the help. I thought it was going to react like a normal drag and drop.

Comment: I haven't messed with HTML5 drag and drop, but I'd imagine you have to tell it what to do regardless.